# Extjs - Newbie. Cannot use reusuable function

Tags: extjs

This code is supposed to call the `stapler()` function, instead it shows a blank page

```
Function stapler(){
    Ext.Msg.show({
        title: 'Milton',
        msg: 'Have you seen my staplersirji?',
        buttons: {
            yes: true,
            no: true,
            cancel: true
        }
    });
} 
Ext.onReady(stapler());
```

No dialogue box is opening in the page. But if i do a inline it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay,
Here it is.
@Evan is correct.
 The reference is what i need to pass. @Anish The function name will be in small character 'f'.

So the anser is the combination of the above two answers.

```
function stapler()
{  
Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL = 'images/s.gif';
Ext.Msg.show(
        {
title: 'Milton',
msg: 'Have you seen my staplersir?',
buttons: {
yes: true,
no: true,
cancel: true
}
}
        );
}
Ext.onReady(stapler);
```

Answer (score 3):

`Ext.onReady` expects a reference to a function. Instead, you're executing the function and passing the result, which in this case, will be `undefined`.

You want:
`Ext.onReady(stapler);`

Comment: @LorenzMeyer that is because Ext is ready.  If it wasn't ready the stapler code would be executed before Ext is ready.

Answer (score 1):

Change Functions capital 'F' to small 'f'

```
function stapler(){
    Ext.Msg.show({
        title: 'Milton',
        msg: 'Have you seen my staplersirji?',
        buttons: {
            yes: true,
            no: true,
            cancel: true
        }
    });
} 
Ext.onReady(stapler());
```

Comment: Just copy this code and paste it in firebug console after you entered into [ext demo page](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/extjs-build/examples/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#basic-panels). Then after i got a positive result